# How to use a prefix "N" in LINQ query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I know how to use a prefix "N" in raw SQL query. (For unicode string)

But how to use a prefix N in LINQ query? any suggestion?

------------update------------

Below is the log generated by LINQ:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET [Content] = @p1
WHERE ([ID] = @p0)
-- @p0: Input BigInt (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [3]
-- @p1: Input Text (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [こんにちは]
```

There's no N in the above generated SQL statement.

(Note I've set datatype of `Content` as `nvarchar`)

Comment: What do you mean by prefix 'N' ? Please share your code.

Comment: @JeevanJose I think he'd like to have all string literals within SQL generated by LINQ marked as Unicode, using `N'string literal'` syntax.

Comment: For me it appears that LINQ adds the N automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`EntityFunctions.AsUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.asunicode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method